# Simplest way to send a notification to Evernote web application?

Tags: webhooks, evernote

I'm not even sure if this is possible/options to look into.

I wrote an email-based sync where a user has a note in Evernote and when the user sends an email from Evernote to a website endpoint, I want the end point to notify the user that their request was received on Evernote.

I don't know if this is even possible. I just want to say "email received" sort of thing.

Closest thing I could think of is having an evernote with the contents updated (sync log). It's kind of like a webhook for Slack but looking for Evernote.

To clarify: The user is currently on Evernote (website) looking at their note, they send the email (from here to share the current note) I want a popup/notification of some sort to say "Email received" I don't know if there is a system for this or not. I don't think so.

Edit: In the meantime I just setup a slack webhook notification

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to programmatically cause a notification to occur/appear within an Evernote client application. You could implement something that's external to Evernote using your own notification mechanism like push notification on mobile, SignalR, etc. but that would be dependent on the user's environment.